# Google cloud memorystore and Google AppEngine standard with python 3

Tags: google-cloud-memorystore

Is it possible to use memorystore with python 3 on GAE standard env? From faq at https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/faq it is clear that it can’t be use with GAE standard but since restrictions are different between python 3 and 2, it might be usable? Python 3 env is not supporting mecache right now and redislab requires another account /subscription managed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately currently it is not possible to access Memorystore from AppEngine Standard environment (even with python 3).

Please see the relevant links: https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#connecting

Also this is being tracked as a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112411170

Answer (score 1):

It is now available through any standard Redis client, check here  https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/redis-overview#connecting