# Memcache for App Engine standard environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-memorystore, redislabs

I am migrating my Python 2.7 App Engine to App Engine 3.7 runtime (standard environment).

I notice that Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#migrating_between_python_2_and_python_3_on_the_app_engine_standard_environment) suggests using a third party service like Redis Labs Cloud as an alternative for Memcache.

> The Memcache service is not available in Python 3. If you need access
>   to a hosted caching service, you can use a third party memcache
>   service like Redis Labs Cloud.

Is there any reason why they wouldn't be recommending their own Cloud Memorystore for this?

From what I can see from other SO posts [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810049/google-cloud-memorystore-and-google-appengine-standard-with-python-3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609767/memcache-alternatives-for-app-engine-standard-second-generation-runtimes), it sounds like it didn't work in the standard environment until recently. So this may just be a timing issue from when their original documentation was released until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55697931/1308883), at this moment, to make Cloud Memorystore work with App Engine standard 2nd gen runtimes, you'll need to use [VPC connectors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/connecting-vpc).

However, VPC connectors are still in [beta](https://cloud.google.com/products/#product-launch-stages).

Since products in beta have no SLAs and no technical support obligations, they are usually not recommended in a production environment.

I guess they'll wait until VPC connectors are GA to recommend Cloud Memorystore as a Memcache alternative.

Also, it could just be an oversight. You should probably provide feeback (top right on the doc page) mentioning this.